# R' Elazar Hakalir's kerovah for Pesach and reason for אותו ואת בנו

Tags: passover, song-poetry, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, shiluach-haken

Over Yom Tov I was looking at R' Elazar Hakalir's kerovah for the second day of Pesach, which is in the Daniel Goldschmidt machzor (available on Otzar Hachochmah, search for גולדשמידט) starting on page 108. The "mechayeh", which goes right before ברוך אתה ה' מחיה המתים, goes like this:

> מה אילו פלאי נסיך
> מתנוסס נס את מנסיך
> נאור רחמיך על כל מעשיך
> נפלאים יתר את עמוסיך
>
> סוך מסך רעל ללודים מסכת
> שיח נואקיך עת שם הסכית
> עורים בעברתך חשכת
> עברים באברתך סכת
>
> פצת תנוך הטו ואל תחטאו
> פסילי פורכים לעמם להטו
> צאן לפסח משכו ושחטו
> צדקו אותו ואת בנו ביום אחד בל תשחטו
>
> > ככתוב: וְשֹׁ֖ור אֹו־שֶׂ֑ה אֹתֹ֣ו וְאֶת־בְּנֹ֔ו לֹ֥א תִשְׁחֲט֖וּ בְּיֹ֥ום אֶחָֽד׃
> > ונאמר: יוֹדֵ֣עַ צַ֭דִּיק נֶ֣פֶשׁ בְּהֶמְתּ֑וֹ וְֽרַחֲמֵ֥י רְ֝שָׁעִ֗ים אַכְזָרִֽי׃
> > ונאמר: ט֤וֹב יְהוָה֙ לְקוָֹ֔ו לְנֶ֖פֶשׁ תִּדְרְשֶֽׁנּוּ׃
> > ונאמר: טוֹב־יְהוָ֥ה לַכֹּ֑ל וְ֝רַחֲמָ֗יו עַל־כָּל־מַעֲשָֽׂיו׃
> > ונאמר: צִדְקָֽתְךָ֨ ׀ כְּֽהַרְרֵי־אֵ֗ל מִ֭שְׁפָּטֶךָ תְּהֹ֣ום רַבָּ֑ה אָ֤דָֽם־וּבְהֵמָ֖ה תֹושִׁ֣יעַ יְהוָֽה׃
> > ונאמר: כְּרַחֵ֣ם אָ֭ב עַל־בָּנִ֑ים רִחַ֥ם יְ֝הוָ֗ה עַל־יְרֵאָֽיו׃
> > ונאמר: הַטּ֤וּ אׇזְנְכֶם֙ וּלְכ֣וּ אֵלַ֔י שִׁמְע֖וּ וּתְחִ֣י נַפְשְׁכֶ֑ם וְאֶכְרְתָ֤ה לָכֶם֙ בְּרִ֣ית עֹולָ֔ם חַֽסְדֵ֥י דָוִ֖ד הַנֶּאֱמָנִֽים׃
> > ונאמר: יְהוָ֛ה מָסַ֥ךְ בְּקִרְבָּ֖הּ ר֣וּחַ עִוְעִ֑ים וְהִתְע֤וּ אֶת־מִצְרַ֨יִם֙ בְּכָֽל־מַעֲשֵׂ֔הוּ כְּהִתָּעֹ֥ות שִׁכֹּ֖ור בְּקִיאֹֽו׃
> > ונאמר: נָ֘תַ֤תָּה לִּירֵאֶ֣יךָ נֵּ֭ס לְהִתְנֹוסֵ֑ס מִ֝פְּנֵ֗י קֹ֣שֶׁט סֶֽלָה׃
> > ונאמר: וְנָגַ֧ף יְהוָ֛ה אֶת־מִצְרַ֖יִם נָגֹ֣ף וְרָפֹ֑וא וְשָׁ֨בוּ֙ עַד־יְהוָ֔ה וְנֶעְתַּ֥ר לָהֶ֖ם וּרְפָאָֽם׃
> > ונאמר: מַה־גָּדְל֣וּ מַעֲשֶׂ֣יךָ יְהוָ֑ה מְ֝אֹ֗ד עָמְק֥וּ מַחְשְׁבֹתֶֽיךָ׃ ‏
>
> מחשבותיך לרחמנו
> מפעלותיך לרוממנו
> מעורר רדומינו
> מרעיף מרוממנו

([Most machzorim](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=BEQ9AAAAcAAJ&pg=PP224) from the last 500 years skip the pesukim in this and similar piyutim.  The Goldschmidt machzorim put them back in.)

The piyut itself highlights Hashem's mercy on us and punishment against the Egyptians.  The pesukim add a new dimension and connect this more directly to the pasuk that forbids slaughtering a mother and child animal on the same day (which is the second pasuk of that day's leining, because this is the second piyut in the sequence).  The idea seems to be that just like Hashem has mercy on animals and forbids slaughtering them on the same day, He also had mercy on us and redeemed us from Egypt, and (second to last pasuk) He also had mercy on the Egyptians and eventually let them recover.

This sounds exactly like the kind of thing you're *not* allowed to say in davening:

> הָאוֹמֵר עַל קַן צִפּוֹר יַגִּיעוּ רַחֲמֶיךָ, וְעַל טוֹב יִזָּכֵר שְׁמֶךָ, מוֹדִים מוֹדִים, מְשַׁתְּקִין אוֹתוֹ.
>
> If someone says [in davening] "Your mercy extends to a bird's nest" ... we make him be quiet.
>
> ([Berachos 5:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.5.3) and [Megillah 4:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Megillah.4.9))

So what's going on in this piyut?  Am I understanding it wrong?  Is *oso ve'es beno* different than *shiluach hakein* for some reason ([the Rambam holds that it's not](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.9.7))?  Does R' Elazar Hakalir disagree with the mishnah ([as the Rambam does in hashkafah, though not necessarily in halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110717/11532); this is easiest to say according to the earliest estimates of when he lived)?

Comment: See Devarim Rabbah 6:1 and Moreh Nevuchim 3:48

Comment: [Tosfos in Megillah 25a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=25&format=text) asks this question in the name of R Elchanan.

Comment: @David Good catch! I see Maharsha in Chiddushei Agados says to look at his Chiddushei Halacha, but he doesn’t have anything in Chiddushei Halacha, neither there in Megillah nor its parallel in Berachos.